# Windows service consuming a lot of memory

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windows-services

I have a windows service that on the OnStart method, calls a method that has an infinite loop. Everything works fine but after some time the used memory goes really high(around 2 GB). This windows service process hundred of records per second so it might not be a problem, but when you start it the first time the memory consumption is fine, it is just after some days it goes high.

I'm trying to find is there a place where I need to dispose of an object but I'm out of ideas.
Here is the code:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using Library;
using Library.Classes;

namespace Events
{
    public partial class ServiceEvent : ServiceBase
    {
        string CT_BACK_GND_PROCESS_TIME = "BackGndProcessTime";
        string CT_ParallelismType = "ParallelismType";

        readonly static string CT_ProcessingMethod = "ProcessingMethod";
        readonly static string CT_SmartProcessingAmount = "SmartProcessingAmount";
        readonly static string CT_ParallelismCap = "ParallelismCap";

        int minUnitId;
        int maxUnitId;
        string idGuid;
        int execType;
        int versionType;
        bool _IsStop = false;
        Functions library;
        Thread threadEvents;

        public ServiceEvent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            library = new Functions();
        }

        #region Window Service Events

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog.Log = "Events records";
            eventLog.Source = "Events records";
            eventLog.WriteEntry("WS Events On Start");

            Functions.SetFakeHttpContext();

            //Caching the Ids
            library.GetIds();

            minUnitId = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinUnitId"]);
            maxUnitId = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxUnitId"]);

            execType = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExecType"]); //0 - Sequencial | 1 - Parallel
            threadEvents = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessEvents));
            
            threadEvents.IsBackground = true;
            threadEvents.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("WS Events On Stop");
            this._IsStop = true;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Main Methods

        public void ProcessEvents()
        {
            // do this loop forever (or until the service is stopped)
            while (!this._IsStop)
            {
                try
                {
                    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    idGuid = guid.ToString();

                    int sleepingTime = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CT_BACK_GND_PROCESS_TIME]);

                       
                    List<EventInfo> eventList = library.GetAllEventsInfo(minUnitId, maxUnitId);
                    //There are some events to process

                    if (eventList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Functions.LogForTimingDebugging(minUnitId.ToString() + " | " + idGuid + "| WS PROCESS_LOCKSTATE_EVENTS", "BEGIN", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff")
                            + " | COUNT: " + eventList.Count.ToString()); //Processing time - new debug log
                        
                        var uniqueIds = eventList.Select(x => x.UnitId).Distinct().ToList();
                        long minId = eventList.Min(x => x.IdEvent);
                        long maxId = eventList.Max(x => x.IdEvent);

                        int processingMethod = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CT_ProcessingMethod]);

                        if (processingMethod == 0) // Normal
                        {
                            if (execType == 1) //In Parallel
                            {
                                Parallel.ForEach(uniqueIds, (id) =>
                                {
                                    ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                });
                            }
                            else if (execType == 0) //Sequencial
                            {
                                foreach (var id in uniqueIds)
                                {
                                    ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (processingMethod == 1) //In parallel with cap
                        {
                            int parallelismCap = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CT_ParallelismCap]);

                            if (uniqueIds.Count > parallelismCap)
                            {
                                int iterations = (uniqueIds.Count + parallelismCap - 1) / parallelismCap;

                                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                                {
                                    int currentPos = i * parallelismCap;
                                    int count = (currentPos + parallelismCap > uniqueIds.Count ? uniqueIds.Count - currentPos : parallelismCap);
                                    var subList = uniqueIds.GetRange(currentPos, count);
                                    Parallel.ForEach(subList, (id) =>
                                    {
                                        ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (execType == 1) //In Parallel
                                {
                                    Parallel.ForEach(uniqueIds, (id) =>
                                    {
                                        ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                    });
                                }
                                else if (execType == 0) //Sequencial
                                {
                                    foreach (var id in uniqueIds)
                                    {
                                        ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (processingMethod == 2) //Smart processing
                        {
                            int smartProcessingAmount = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CT_SmartProcessingAmount]);

                            if (eventList.Count >= smartProcessingAmount)
                            {
                                Parallel.ForEach(uniqueIds, (id) =>
                                {
                                    ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (execType == 1) //In Parallel
                                {
                                    Parallel.ForEach(uniqueIds, (id) =>
                                    {
                                        ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                    });
                                }
                                else if (execType == 0) //Sequencial
                                {
                                    foreach (var id in uniqueIds)
                                    {
                                        ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (processingMethod == 3) //Smart processing with cap
                        {
                            int smartProcessingAmount = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CT_SmartProcessingAmount]);

                            if (eventList.Count >= smartProcessingAmount)
                            {
                                int parallelismCap = Convert.ToInt32(Functions.GetContentTemplate(CT_ParallelismCap, 0));

                                if (uniqueIds.Count > parallelismCap)
                                {
                                    int iterations = (uniqueIds.Count + parallelismCap - 1) / parallelismCap;

                                    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                                    {
                                        int currentPos = i * parallelismCap;
                                        int count = (currentPos + parallelismCap > uniqueIds.Count ? uniqueIds.Count - currentPos : parallelismCap);
                                        var subList = uniqueIds.GetRange(currentPos, count);
                                        Parallel.ForEach(subList, (id) =>
                                        {
                                            ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Parallel.ForEach(uniqueIds, (id) =>
                                    {
                                        ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                    });
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (execType == 1) //In Parallel
                                {
                                    Parallel.ForEach(uniqueIds, (id) =>
                                    {
                                        ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                    });
                                }
                                else if (execType == 0) //Sequencial
                                {
                                    foreach (var id in uniqueIds)
                                    {
                                        ProcessOneUnit(id, eventList);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        library.DeleteMultiplesEventsInfo(minUnitId, maxUnitId, minId, maxId);

                        Functions.LogForTimingDebugging(minUnitId.ToString() + " | " + idGuid + "| WS PROCESS_EVENTS", "END", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff")); //Processing time - new debug log
                    }
                    
                    Thread.Sleep(sleepingTime); //Wait for next iteration based on Global Content Template
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Functions.SendEventLog(minUnitId.ToString() + " | WS PROCESS_EVENTS", "General Error", ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            eventLog.WriteEntry("WS PROCESS_EVENTS SERVICE STOPPED | " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
        }

        public void ProcessOneUnit(int id, List<EventInfo> eventList)
        {
            var unitEvents = new List<EventInfo>();
            unitEvents.AddRange(eventList.Where(x => x.UnitId == id).ToList());

            foreach (var item in unitEvents)
            {
                library.ProcessOneEventInfo(item);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

Comment: On first glance I don't see anything weird. So what's in library.ProcessOneEventInfo? Or Functions.LogForTimingDebugging?

Comment: The Functions.LogForTimingDebugging is used for saving logs and the library.ProcessOneEventInfo has several conditional statements (around 1200 lines) that will be too long to be added here. I don't know if changing the declaration of the library variable (library = new Functions()) to be inside the loop will make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler?

Comment: Does the memory usage keep rising?

Comment: @DavidLibido I haven't used it because this memory consumption only happens in production which I might not be able to use a profiler but I will try to see what I can do about it.

Comment: @CaiusJard It looks that way. The service starts consuming around 1% of CPU and 80 MB of memory, and after a few days goes all the way to 20-35% CPU usage and almost 2 GB of memory. The logic inside is simple, read records from the database every 1 second(around 10 - 50 records), process the records, and start over. Processing the records is something simple, based on the value of it, it is updating some tables in SQL

Comment: Can you show us the data access code

Comment: @CaiusJard specifically what do you want to see?

Comment: Erm.. the Functions class perhaps?

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue even after disposing all objects and clearing lists.